# How to Set Custom Time for setInterval() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Need to set different time for each interval, Using like a variable?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
    {
        //do something....
    }, need_custom_time_for_each_interval);
});
```

Comment: Instead you can try multiple setTimeouts with different timeout values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `setInterval` function, you need to know the time when to reset your interval.

In this example, we create an interval with 500ms to print the id. When the id becomes to `10`, we *reset* it by clearing the current interval and creating the new one.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var id = 1;

    var refreshId;

    var implement = function() 
    {
        $('body').append('<div>' + id++ + '</div>');
        
        if (id === 10) {
            clearInterval(refreshId);
            
            refreshId = setInterval(implement, 100);
        }
        
        if (id === 20) {
            clearInterval(refreshId);
        }
    };

    refreshId = setInterval(implement, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function customSetTime(customTime) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    //do something....      
  }, customTime);
}

customSetTime(500); // example usage
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setInterval you would probably want to call setTimeout from within the callback function. Then you could pass a custom value each time it executes.

Comment: Please, Can you provide me the examples?

Answer (score 0):

```
const timeouts = [1000, 2000, 3000];
const timeout_fds = cb => timeouts.map(t => setTimeout(cb, t));
timeout_fds(() => console.log('Hey ', Math.random()))
```

Comment: I commented on his question and also this is just a small code & self explanatory I guess.